# Name of this movie that was filmed as a terrorist attack/civil war on an unknown city in the USA?

Tags: identify-this-movie, action

My parents watched a movie and I caught glimpses of it...they wont tell me the name of the movie, and it was on netflix...not anymore:

## Points of detail not related to the plot:

- **Language**: American English (English with the US accent)
- **Country filmed in**: USA
- **Setting**: USA
- **Characters**:  Most were American Caucasian, others (the opposition) were what looked like Islamic or Muslim with AK47's (also caucasian but a few were black skinned).
- **What I remember from the title**: It was three words as the title, the last word was *murders* as I saw.
- **Colour or black and white**: It was in colour.
- **Last seen**: A few days ago (or specifically a few nights ago)
- **How much of the film was seen**: Only small portions of it, maybe a few key scenes every 30-60 seconds.
- **Genre**: Terrorist attack/war genre.
- **I don't know who the protagonist was**

  ***Plot as follows (described scenes wont be in any particular order):***

## The plane crash:

- There was this grey warplane that was flying through the air
- The plane was heading straight for a tall building in an unknown building in the USA and in an unknown state
- The plane flew *through* the building
- It crash landed in large rectangular grass area with one of its wings on fire
- Civilians had to run or jump out of the way to avoid being killed.

## Hostile army moves in:

- There was a bunch of men, they wore clothing most commonly found on insurgents of the middle east or near east.
- They had I am fairly sure they were AK47's
- They ran and took cover, ran and took cover as an advancement of war on the enemy being the Americans.
- They fought like they had enver fought before.

## The American army moves in:

- I know I saw a formation of armoured vehicles from the Americans move in on a road next to a river (I think it was a river I am not sure)
- I heard an officer say:

  > There is a gunfight in the east of the city.
- I also heard the mere mention of the '*White House*' but not sure when this comes into it.
- I don't recall much from the US Army but I know that they put up a stiff fight against the insurgents.
- The vehicles I believe were APC's (Armoured Personell Carriers), Humvees and another sort similar to the Australian Bushmaster only it was a grey colour, like the United Nation's vehicles:

[image: Vehicle similar to this one]

## The building:

I do know for sure that the building the plane crashed into had in fact collapsed in a pile of rubble and huge grey dust cloud.

## ***End of plot explanation***

**Yeah sorry guys, there isn't much I remember form the movie but I have described in as much detail as I remember about the movie.**

I totally understand if there is going to be questions, but this is all I can provide and even more hope someone know what I am on about.

Comment: Are you sure that unknown building in the USA is really in USA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean [Olympus Has Fallen](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2302755/combined) from 2013. No 'murders' in the title, though (though there are 'attack' and 'assault' in some of the foreign titles for this film).

> When the White House (Secret Service Code: "Olympus") is captured by a terrorist mastermind and the President is kidnapped, disgraced former Presidential Secret Service Agent Mike Banning finds himself trapped within the building. As our national security team scrambles to respond, they are forced to rely on Banning's inside knowledge to help retake the White House, save the President and avert an even bigger disaster.

You can see the exact plane crash that you described in the clip below around 2:30, but this indeed happens in a known city (Washington DC) and to a known building. A huge gray Lockheed is shot, clips the Washington Monument and crashes into the grass in the National Mall with its wing on fire while people run out of the way, followed by the Monument crumbling and collapsing:

Comment: I said unknown because I didn't know what the city was named. But yes that was it, thank you. The one with the word *murders* was probably from some advertised movie coming up :P